# Find the table number in a html page using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, html-table

I am trying to open a IE site (related to customer ticket details) through a macro. I need to identify one HTML Table on the webpage, and copy its content to Excel through a clipboard.

For each ticket accessed, the table number is varying. For the first ticket it ran successfully, but for the second ticket, the table number changed.

How can I get the HTML table number for each ticket, as it is a variable?

```
sub sample()

Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim Clipboard As Object
Dim Tabl_name As IHTMLElement

last_lin1st = Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(2).Find("Sum").Row
val_nci = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value

With ThisWorkbook
    .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "temp"
End With

Set ie = Nothing
Set IeDoc = Nothing
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
strHTML = "webURL"

ie.navigate strHTML

Set IeDoc = ie.document
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

msg = ie.document.Body.innerhtml

Set Clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject

Clipboard.SetText ie.document.getElementsByTagName("Table")(32).outerHTML
Clipboard.PutInClipboard

Worksheets("temp").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

The table number for the first ticket is 32, which is working. For the next ticket it is 28 and different for the rest of the tickets. I am stuck in finding the table number, as I need to copy that table and paste it in an Excel sheet for every ticket.

Below is sample HTML code of the page. Let me know which table name should I enter in the getElementsbyTagName:

```
  <div class="issuePanelContainer" id="issue_actions_container">

  <table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=34%><b>Transition</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=15%><b>Status Change Time</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=15% align=center><b>Execution Times</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=18%><b>Last Executer</b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#f0f0f0" width=18%><b>Last Execution Date</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td bgcolor="#ffffff" width=34% valign=top>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td width=7% valign=center>                                           
    <img src="/images/icons/status_generic.gif" height="16" width="16" alt="New" title="New - The issue is created" />                        </td>
    <td width=40% valign=top>
        New
    </td>
    <td align="center" nowrap="nowrap" width=6% valign=top>
    <img src="/images/icons/arrow_right_small.gif" align="absmiddle" border="0" height="16" width="16">
    </td>
        <td width=7% valign=center>         
        <img src="/images/icons/status_open.gif" height="16" width="16" alt="Opened" title="Opened - The issue is open and ready for the assignee to start work on it." />
    </td>
    <td width=40% valign=top>
     Opened
     </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width=15% valign=top align=right>
         <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td valign=top

         2d 20h 
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
         <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width=15% valign=top align=center>
     <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td valign=top align="center">
      1
     </td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width=18% valign=top>
         <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td valign=top>
     <a id="email_470121" href="/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=123456">username</a>
         </td>
     </tr>
         </table>             
         </td>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#ffffff" width=18% valign=top align=right>
         <table width="100%">
     <tr>
     <td valign=top align=right>
         26/11/2017 12:47 PM
         </td>
         </tr>
         </table>
         </td>
         </tr>
```

Comment: What is a "Table number" from an HTML perspective? I've never heard of such a thing. Perhaps something specific to the HTML you are scraping? Without seeing the HTML you are trying to scrape it's really not something we can help solve.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I assume the downvotes are because it's impossible to help you with the information you have in your question. Would you be able to scrape this HTML without seeing it? The "Close" votes suggest the same "Unclear what you are asking"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.But how can I share the HTML code. Its a very big code. I was just looking for an example, if anything can be done with it. Also, its something I cant share on this platform, as it has so much sensitive info.

Comment: What value is there in the table that will help you determine the right one? Is there a specific text value? Even better is there an id or specific bit of html only found in that table that is always present in that table? You can share entire html through https://pastebin.com/ and swop the values of sensitive information for dummy info so long as html is preserved and unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

You must loop through all the tables to find the information you are looking for.

If this table position changes like you are saying then this table must have a specific word/text that must differentiate it from the rest or you wont be able to make this work.

Here is how you loop and look through it.

```
Dim foundData as Boolean
Set tables = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("Table")
For x = 0 to tables.Length Step 1
    'You may need to use innerText or inner/outerHTML to find the text
    If tables(x).innerText Like "*TEXT IN TABLE*" Then
        'Table found, Copy the Data
        Set Clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
        Clipboard.SetText tables(x).outerHTML
        Clipboard.PutInClipboard
        Worksheets("temp").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
        foundData = True
        Exit For 'Exit Loop since the data was found
    End If
Next x
'Check if data was found after leaving the loop
If foundData <> True Then
    MsgBox "The Data Was Not Found on Any Tables"
End If
```

I've Edited the code to add the copy lines if the table is found.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. But the problem is that it is copying the whole page on the excel, and after the paste step, it is showing the message "Can't enter break mode at this time" and as soon as I click on Coninue button, it is displaying run-time error 91 where I have to end the code, because there is no other option left. Is there something I am missing on?